# Разработка сайта - с какой части начинать?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, frontend

При добавлении новой функциональности в существующий веб-проект, необходимо сначала реализовать её на сервере или на клиентской стороне?

Comment: Зависит от функциональности. (c) Кэп.

Comment: Это как бы две почти не пересекающиеся задачи.

"Не пересекающиеся", потому что серверу должно быть безразлично как реализовано это на клиенте, аналогично и для клиента должен быть безразличен сервер.

"Почти", т.к. все-таки есть точка соприкосновения, а именно - взаимодействие сервера и клиента.

Т.е. на этапе проектирования продумываете интерфейс, далее параллельно разрабатываете клиент и сервер, а уже потом допиливаете несостыковки.

Comment: Необходимо сначала ее запроектировать, чтобы четко знать, как должны себя вести сервер и клиент и в каком формате реализовывать обмен данных. А начинать стоит оттуда, откуда удобнее в конкретной задаче, по сути, не важно. В командах, к примеру, front-end и back-end работают параллельно, поскольку знают, что по документированной части от них требуется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В идеале задача распараллеливается, если вы один делаете, то я бы стал делать так:

- Определяется основная концепция того, что должно быть реализовано в порядке важности.
- Выбирается взаимодействие бекенда и фронтенда (get/post/ajax/sockets...)
- Делается дизайн основанный на необходимом функционале и способе коммуникации с бекендом

  - Тут можно выделить подпункты связанные с разработкой UI/UX
- Делается верстка по дизайну
- Пишем минимальную часть на бекенде
- Пишем минимальною логику на фронтенде
- Тестируем минимальный функционал, возможно делаем unit-тесты
- Допиливаем остальное, тестируем, исправляем баги, дописываем unit-тесты

Подход может быть разным для каждого человека, а работа в команде предполагает другую последовательность действий.